# Binary Search Tree In Order Predecessor not removing node

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I've been trying to get my bst to work, but the issue persists that the node succeeding the removed node is never removed.

```
[ <P, 1>, <C, 26>, <U, 3>, <B, 293>, <H, 1>, <R, 12>, <V, 42>, null, null, null, <K, 465>, <Q, 465>, <S, 42>, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, <L, 465>, null, null, null, <T, 465>, ]

[ <P, 1>, <C, 26>, **<T, 465>**, <B, 293>, <H, 1>, <R, 12>, <V, 42>, null, null, null, <K, 465>, <Q, 465>, <S, 42>, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, <L, 465>, null, null, null, **<T, 465>**, ]
```

- [BST : inOrder successor and predecessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235533/bst-inorder-successor-and-predecessor)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893956/binarysearchtree-predecessor-algorithm
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/35219/in-order-predecessor-bst-review

and looking at these other implementations and adapting for the proper properties of my tree:

- http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/BST.java.html
- http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html
- https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Trees/code/BST.java

```
public class BinarySearchTree<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value extends Comparable<Value>>{

    class Node extends KeyValuePair<Key, Value> {
        private int position = -1;
        private Node leftChild = null;
        private Node rightChild = null;
        private KeyValuePair<Key, Value> pair = new KeyValuePair<Key, Value>();

        // getters and setters

        public Node findMax() {
            Node newCur = this;
            while (newCur.getRightChild() != null) {
                newCur = newCur.getRightChild();
            }
            return newCur;
        }
    }

    private int pos = -1; // helps keep track of where the node is in the tree
    private int bstSize = 0;
    private int largestPos = -1;
    protected Node root = null;


    private Node findKey(Key keyToMatch, Node current) {
        if (current == null || current.getKey() == keyToMatch) {
            return current;
        } else if (keyToMatch.compareTo(current.getKey()) < 0) {
            return findKey(keyToMatch, current.getLeftChild());
        } else {
            return findKey(keyToMatch, current.getRightChild());
        }
    }

    private Node put(Node node, Node temp) {
        if (node == null) {
            node = temp;
        }

        else if (temp.getKey().compareTo(node.getKey()) < 0) {
            node.setLeftChild(put(node.getLeftChild(), temp));
        }

        else if (temp.getKey().compareTo(node.getKey()) > 0) {
            node.setRightChild(put(node.getRightChild(), temp));
        }

        return node;
    }

    @Override
    public Value put(Key key, Value value) {
        if (key == null || value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Node temp = new Node();
        temp.setKey(key);
        temp.setValue(value);

        Node oldNode = null;
        Value oldVal = null;

        if (root == null) {
            root = temp;
        } else {
            oldNode = findKey(key, root);

            if (oldNode != null) { // means there was a key match
                oldVal = oldNode.getValue();
                oldNode.setValue(value);
            }

            else {
                put(root, temp);
            }
        }

        return oldVal;
    }

    private Node remove(Node current, Key key) {
        Node temp = new Node();

        if(current == null) {
            return null;
        }
        else if(key.compareTo(current.getKey()) < 0) {
            remove(current.getLeftChild(), key);
        }
        else if(key.compareTo(current.getKey()) > 0) {
            remove(current.getRightChild(), key);
        }
        else {
            if (current.getRightChild() == null) return current.getLeftChild();
            else if(current.getLeftChild() == null) return current.getRightChild();
            current.setKey(current.getLeftChild().findMax().getKey());
            current.setValue(current.getLeftChild().findMax().getValue());
            current.setLeftChild(remove(current.getLeftChild(), current.getKey()));
        }

        return current;
    }

    @Override
    public Value remove(Key key) {
        if (key == null || root == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Node current = findKey(key, root);
        Value val = null;

        if(current == null) {
            return val;
        }
        else {
            val = current.getValue();

            remove(root, key);
        }
        return val;
    }

    public KeyValuePair<Key, Value>[] breadthFirstTraversal() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        KeyValuePair<Key, Value>[] bftArray = new KeyValuePair[largestPos];
        KeyValuePair<Key, Value> nodeVal = null;

        if (!isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 1; i < bftArray.length + 1; i++) {
                keyPos.reset();
                if (positionFound(i)) {
                    nodeVal = findPosKey(root, i);
                    bftArray[i - 1] = nodeVal;
                } else {
                    bftArray[i - 1] = null;
                }

            }
        }

        return bftArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you learn by stepping through this with a debugger?

Comment: @DavidWallace I didn't find anything... I've been at this for about 5 hours. Fixing other problems along the way.. this just happened to pop up under one of the cases.

Comment: OK, but your debugger should tell you immediately why the thing isn't getting deleted.  So it would be helpful to share what information the debugger DID tell you - it would save time for everyone who wants to help you.

Comment: @DavidWallace My debugger says nothing of the sort. All I do for debugging is use print statements at points in the code to decipher what is happening. It all works fine. It's just that the node where previous ones were (the predecessor) does not accept the `= null` statement. I honestly do not know what is happening in my code.

Comment: OK, in that case, I strongly recommend learning to use a proper debugger.  Then you'll be able to step through the code, see which parts run and which parts don't run, and what value every variable has at every relevant point.  I can guarantee that it would take you a few seconds to work out what's going on here, if  you use a proper debugger.  It's basically one of the most important skills you can learn as a programmer.  If you become a professional programmer, then using a debugger properly will save you literally YEARS over the course of your career.